# ¿Cómo quitar un elemento de un array extraído de una api e imprimirlo en una tabla html?

Tags: php, html, json

Tengo una función para consumir una api. Los datos debo mostrarlos en una tabla, pero antes debo quitar un elemento del array.

Esta es la función para consumir la api y recibe el parámetro rut (obtenido desde un formulario por GET)

```
function TraerDeliveries($rut) {
    $url = 'https://UrlParaExtraerApi?rut=' . $rut;
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => 'Authorization-Key: xxxxxxx',
            'method'  => 'GET'
        )
    );


    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) 
    {
       
    }
    return json_decode($result);

}
```

Este es el array y sus elementos

```
 $deliveries = TraerDeliveries($rut);

//var_dump($deliveries);
//array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["correlativo"]=> string(10) "4024514577" ["rut"]=>string(9) "xxxxxx" ["ot"]=> string(7) "1642739" ["delivery"]=> string(8) "LOGYTECH"       ["fechaPago"]=> string(10) "18/09/2022" } }
```

Acá es donde no sé resolver. Debo imprimir solo los elementos: rut, ot, delivery y fechaPago.
El elemento "correlativo" no se debe imprimir.

```
 $s = "<table>

    <tr>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>RUT</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>ORDEN DE TRANSPORTE</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>DELIVEY</td>
        <td class='tdTitulo'>FECHA DE COMPRA</td>
    </tr>";

 foreach ( $pieces as $r ) {
    $s .= '<tr>';
    foreach ( $r as $v ) {
            $s .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    }
    $s .= '</tr>';
 }



 $s .= "</table>";



 echo "<div class='contenedorTabla2'>".$s."</div>";
```

Comment: Esto debería funcionar: `foreach ( $r as $k=>$v ) { if($k!='correlativo') {$s .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>'; }}` Asumo que en `$r`  vas a tener el array asociativo de los datos que nos muestras en la pregunta.

Comment: es correto lo que dice @A.Cedano no hay necesidad de eliminar datos del array simplemente se pueden ignorar con esa instruccion.

Comment: No funcionó. Supongo que la variable $r debo reemplazarla por mi variable $deliveries  Aun así no funcionó.

Comment: Ahora si!, cometí un error. Funciona Perfecto!, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Asumo que en `$r` vas a tener el array asociativo de los datos que nos muestras en la pregunta.

Puedes apelar a la key de cada valor para discriminar cuando la misma sea `correlativo`.

También, puedes evitar tantas concatenaciones, si usas comillas dobles, puedes meter variables dentro.

```
foreach ( $pieces as $r ) {
    $s .= '<tr>';
    foreach ( $r as $k=>$v ) {
        if( $k!='correlativo' ) {
            # Ojo aquí a las comillas dobles
            $s .= "<td>$v</td>";
        }
    }
    $s .= '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yo ocuparia:

```
unset($r['correlativo']);
```

Esto lo que hará es quitar el key y el value de correlativo.